# PHP rename array keys in multidimensional array with array content

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array:

```
array(2) 
{
      [0]=>
      array(358) {
        ["listing ID"]=>
        string(0) "253321"
        ["buyername"]=>
        string(0) "will"
        ["buyeraddress"]=>
        string(0) "938 s st"
    }
      [1]=>
      array(358) {
        ["listing ID"]=>
        string(0) "1231231"
        ["buyername"]=>
        string(0) "matt"
        ["buyeraddress"]=>
        string(0) "22 n st"
      }
    }
```

using PHP, how would i rename the object [0]=>array(358) from 0 to another name that is pulled out with in that own array... for example to name [0]=>array(358) to the ["listing ID"]=> string(0) "253321" . so the object would now be named [253321]=>array(358).

and  [0]=>array(358) would change to [1231231]=>array(358) which is the ListingID with in that objects array.

Comment: Can you share the code you have? What have you tried?

Comment: Or name a function/control structure that might be used?

Comment: You chose a loop and unset over a built-in function that does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $array[$v['listing ID']] = $v;
    unset($array[$k]);
}
```

Iterate over the array. Add a new element and assign it a key using a  value from the current element. Then remove the current element. Or iterate over your array and simply add new elements to some fresh array you've just instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

One use of `array_column` is to index the array by a specific column:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'listing ID');
```

However, if this comes from a database then you should build it that way when fetching the rows.